# custom header text and headrule

Tags: header-footer, rules, fancyhdr, documentclass-writing

Using `mweclass` **LaTeX** class (`report` based) is writing a document as follows:

```
\documentclass{mweclass}
\title{MWE}
\author{J. Doe}
\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{mwetest}
  \maketitle
  \pagestyle{mwetest}
  \chapter{One}
  \section{First}
  % LaTeX code ...
\end{document}
```

In the *header* there **must** be a *headrule* on each page at a **fixed offset in height**.

But... when there are any `g`, `q`, `p` etc. letters in the text above (chapter or section names) the headrule is distanced **correctly**. Otherwise, the headrule is "**attaching**" to the text.

In a `mweclass.cls` I have this code for the `mwetest` pagestyle:

```
\newcommand{\ps@mwetest}{%
  \setlength\fancy@headwidth       {\mwe@textwidth}%
  \fancy@setoffs%
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth      {\mwe@headrulewidth}%
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth      {0pt}%
  \renewcommand\footruleskip       {0pt}%
  \def\headrule{\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip-\headrulewidth}%
  \def\footrule{}%
  \def\f@ncyorh{\rightmark~\ \ \ \ \ ~\thepage}%
  \def\f@ncyelh{\thepage~\ \ \ \ \ ~\leftmark}%
  \def\@oddhead{\@fancyhead\fancy@Oolh\@empty\hfil\f@ncyorh\fancy@Oorh}%
  \def\@evenhead{\@fancyhead\fancy@Oelh\f@ncyelh\hfil\@empty\fancy@Oerh}%
  \def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}%
  \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{##1\ -- \ \thechapter}{}}%
  \def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\thechapter.\arabic{section}\ --\ ##1}}%
}
```

Some code is taken from distributed `fancyhdr.sty`, version **3.2**, lines **432-435**. The ***\mwe@textwidth*** and ***\mwe@headrulewidth*** are calculated `OK` by the `mweclass` class before.

The problem is probably something to do with the *baseline* in letters. The *headrule* keeps ***attaching/detaching*** from the *chapter* / *section* names above, whether the text contains letters whose shape in the font prolongs below the baseline; or not.

1. Is there a way to insert *invisible* (that are not typeset) letters in a text? If there were, an easy workaround is to put a `q` in chapter and section names.
2. What is wrong? Except this *mobile* headrule, the header is but `OK`.

I appreciate any reply or suggestions.

Comment: How much experience do you have in writing new document classes? When you use some pieces of code from `fancyhdr`, why don't you simply include the package? It solves your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). We consider the questions a "wiki" material and therefore we don't include "Thanks" in the questions. You can thank the answers by [up-voting them and accepting the one you find best](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Sorry I am a day late answering. Indeed you puzzled me: "When you use some ... package?" I mean, what if macros change names? Though fancyhdr is basic. I write document classes but I don't know `\strut`? I use `LaTeX`, and I haven't seen `\phantom`? Yet, I manage to put `\protect` there? Once I decided to switch from googling to parsing code directly, I gained more trust. I really *liked* how fancyhdr did the @odd/@even, so instead of many howtos, I dropped in. What cannot change my using TeX is that *I can* **calculate page lengths**, and have a clear text language for it; like breathing air.

Comment: Hey! It wasn't meant as any offense, and if you felt like that, I apologize. I asked for your experience because serious breaking in some advanced packages like `fancyhdr` needs extended experience with writing your own low-level macros, because it helps you a lot understand what's going on in the package. Unless I needed some really really complicated tweaking, I always included the package and tweaked it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `\strut` command: it inserts a piece of nothing of the `\height` and `\depth` as large as the largest letters in current font, but having no `\width`.

Comment: Ok, it works like this: \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{##1\strut\ -- \ \thechapter}{}} \def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\thechapter.\arabic{section}\ --\ ##1\strut}}

Answer (score 1):

Invisible characters are made with `\phantom{txt}`, `\hphantom{txt}` or `\vphantom{txt}`. The first takes width and height, the second width only and the third height only into account.

Comment: Ok, it works like \chapter{Name\protect\vphantom{p}}.